# triggered breakpoint when free-ing memory

Tags: c, breakpoints, free

im trying to free the memory that is being used by this bit of code, but it triggers a breakpoint with no hint to why, could anyone explain why

the bit of code in question

```
store(testPool, poolSize - 1, sizeof(str), str);
printf("Test 6: Store / Retrieve past the end of memory\n");
printf("\tStored: %s\n", str);
void* temp = retrieve(testPool, poolSize - 1, sizeof(str) - 1);
if (temp != NULL)
{
    printf("\tRetrieved value\n");
}
else
{
    printf("\tRetrieved NULL\n");
}
freePool(testPool);
```

the error pops up when im trying to free the memory in the pool, and im at a loss to why

```
void freePool(Pool* pool)
{
    if (pool != NULL)
        if (pool->memory != NULL)
        {
            free(pool->memory); //here
            free(pool);
        }

}
```

here is where i alocate the pool with a fixed size

```
const int poolSize = 560;
testPool = allocatePool(poolSize);
```

here is the rest of the code if it helps at all

```
typedef struct _POOL
{
    int size;
    void* memory;

} Pool;

Pool * allocatePool(int n)
{
    Pool *pool =(Pool*) malloc(sizeof(Pool));
    if(pool != NULL)
        pool->memory = malloc(sizeof(char) * n);
        if (pool->memory != NULL)
            if(n > 0)
                pool->size = n;
        else
            free(pool);

    return pool;
}




void store(Pool* pool, int offset, int size, void *object)
{
    if (pool != NULL)
        if (size < pool->size)
            memcpy((char*)pool->memory + offset, object, size);
}

void *retrieve(Pool* pool, int offset, int size)
{
    return (char*)pool->memory + offset;

}
```

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For instance you didn't even post the part where you call `allocatePool`.

Comment: Hint: remove this line: `store(testPool, poolSize - 1, sizeof(str), str);` and look if  `free` still hits the breakpoint. If no, then `store` is most likely overwriting memory that it shouldn't. That `+ offset` in `store` looks fishy.

Comment: i have included where i allocate the pool micheal, you were right about the store method, i commented it out and had no problems, would there be a fix that didnt require me to change the store method call?

Comment: Do you know Dylzan?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36425445/why-is-this-c-programme-sometimes-crashing

Comment: 'I've seen this assignment before here. It purposely attempts to invoke Undefined Behaviour by doing things like "Store / Retrieve past the end of memory". Right? So it's not surprising for it to exhibit random behaviour.' – kaylum

Comment: If it's an assignment, isn't the idea that YOU find out where it's breaking?

Answer (score 0):

You are trashing memory in `store`.

You allocate 560 bytes for your pool.

Then you call `store(testPool, poolsize-1, sizeof(str), str)`.

Let's assume `sizeof(str)` is 30

In `store` you basically do this:

```
memcpy((char*)pool->memory + 559, object, 30);
```

thus writing 29 bytes past the allocated memory, remember `pool->memory` points to a memory slice that is only 560 bytes long.

This leads to undefined behaviour, resulting most of the time in a crashes, either immediatly or later in the program or in other strange behaviour.

The whole program is fishy.

Comment: @MartinJames maybe or maybe not. We actually don't know what the homework is.

Comment: the test is to check is you can allocate past the memory, i presumably have to put some error checking somewhere in my code, im sorry if i mislead you but this is basically homework, i do appriciate all the help tho xx

Comment: @David, since I have spent some time to do part of your homework, you could at least give an upvote.

Comment: @David basically if you write past allocated memory, you get _undefined behaviour_.